# parse XML and insert to DB if exists otherwise UPDATE

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, sql-update, sql-insert

I am parsing a XML file and I would like to **INSERT** the XML elements nodes if id does not exist, OR **UPDATE** record if exists...

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;
//connection to DB here..
//.... .. .. .. ..


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbuser, $password, $dbname,3306);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// Change character set to utf8
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');

$date_modified = strtotime("now");
$business_id = 54;
$xml_link = "https://www.mydomain.gr/test.xml";
$xml_link = $conn->real_escape_string($xml_link);
$xml_link = trim(stripslashes($xml_link));
```

Here I am updating the record "date_modified"..

```
$update_business_xml = $conn->query('UPDATE business_xml SET date_modified="' . $date_modified . '" WHERE business_id=54');
```

Now, in this section of code, I am getting all the ids of products, and put them inside an array

```
$count_errors = 0;
//query to find products ids
$query_ids = $conn->query('SELECT pid FROM products WHERE business_id=54');
$rows_ids = mysqli_num_rows($query_ids);
$count_id = 0;
if($rows_ids > 0) {
    while($exe_ids = mysqli_fetch_object($query_ids)) {
        $arr_ids[$count_id] = $exe_ids->pid;
        $count_id++;
    }
}

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xml_link);           
while($reader->read()) {
    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'product' ) {
        $product = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXml());

        $pid = $product->id;
        $name = $product->name;
        $name = mb_strtolower($name,'UTF-8');
        $mpn = $product->mpn;
        $ean = $product->ean;
        $sku = $product->sku;
        $link = $product->link;
        $price = $product->price;
        $category_id =  $product->category->attributes();
        $category_path = $product->category;
        $category_path = mb_strtolower($category_path,'UTF-8');
        $image = $product->image;
        $availability = $product->availability;
        $size = $product->size;
        $size = mb_strtolower($size,'UTF-8');
        $color = $product->color;
        $color = mb_strtolower($color,'UTF-8');
        $weight = $product->weight;
        $description = $product->description;
        $manufacturer = $product->manufacturer;
        $manufacturer = trim($manufacturer);
        $instock = "Y";
        $product_image = $image;
        $check_product_url = $link;

        $exist_pids = 0;
        if(!empty($pid) || !empty($image) || !empty($price) || !empty($name) || !empty($link) || !empty($manufacturer)) {
            if($category_id == 613 || $category_id == 604 || $category_id == 635) {
```

I have some categories in XML that I do not want them in my DB, so here I am getting the attribute of the category, and check if this product is one of them, just update the status of this record to my DB.

```
                $update_business_xml = $conn->query('UPDATE products SET status=0 WHERE business_id="' . $business_id . '" AND pid= "' . $pid . '"');
                $count_errors++;
            }
            else {
                $status = 1;
                $date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //when insert a pr
                $date_modified = strtotime("now"); //when modify a pr
                $insert_business_xml = $conn->query('INSERT INTO products (business_id,pid,name,category,product_link,price,size,color,weight,description,manufacturer,mpn,ean,image,sku,instock,availability,status,date_added) VALUES("'.$business_id.'", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($pid)) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($name)) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($category_path))) . '", 
                "' . $check_product_url . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($price)) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim(strtolower($size)))) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim(strtolower($color)))) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($weight))) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($description))) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim(strtolower($manufacturer)))) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($mpn))) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($ean))) . '", 
                "' . $product_image . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($sku))) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($instock)) . '", 
                "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($availability)) . '", 
                "' . $status . '", "' . $date . '") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                "business_id='.$business_id.'", 
                "pid=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($pid)) . '", 
                "name=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($name)) . '", 
                "category=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($category_path))) . '", 
                "product_link=' . $check_product_url . '", 
                "price=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($price)) . '", 
                "size=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim(strtolower($size)))) . '", 
                "color=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim(strtolower($color)))) . '", 
                "weight=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($weight))) . '", 
                "description=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($description))) . '", 
                "manufacturer=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim(strtolower($manufacturer)))) . '", 
                "mpn=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($mpn))) . '", 
                "ean=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($ean))) . '", 
                "image=' . $product_image . '", 
                "sku=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($sku))) . '", 
                "instock=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($instock)) . '", 
                "availability=' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($availability)) . '", 
                "status=' . $status . '", 
                "date_modified=' . $date_modified . '"');
```

In the above code I am using the INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in order to check if the id exists, just UPDATE all the values of this record.. If the id does not exist, INSERT this one..
At the beggining of my code as I told, I got all the ids in an array, so here I am erasing the id that have been found..

```
                //erase from arr_ids
                if(($key = array_search($pid, $arr_ids)) !== false) {
                    unset($arr_ids[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $update_business_xml = $conn->query('UPDATE products SET status=0, date_modified="' . $date_modified . '" WHERE business_id="' . $business_id . '" AND pid= "' . $pid . '"');
            $count_errors++;
        }
    } //reader nodeType
} //end while loop
$reader->close();
```

Last but not least, here I am also UPDATE the record with all the rest of the ids that have been left of inside the array..which it means these ids, does not exist or there are not listed inside the XML any more.

```
foreach($arr_ids as $id) {
    $update_business_xml = $conn->query('UPDATE products SET status=0 WHERE business_id="' . $business_id . '" AND pid= "' . $id . '"');
}
```

Finally, I have a simple message in order to see how many errors there are.. By saying errors, I mean how many records of the XML has empty elements (name,price, link, image.. .. etc) and just make an echo..

```
//var_dump($arr_ids);
$insert_messages = "Your XML file has been updated successfully! We found <strong>" . $count_errors . "</strong> errors. In case errors found, please check your dashboard!";
echo $insert_messages;
$conn->close();
?>
```

All this code is inside a php file, that runs as a **cronjob**!
Now the problem and my question is, that I did not see the UPDATE running correctly or not at all, because the date_modified is always NULL inside my DB, which is the initialize value.. What am I missing? (and generally what could I do in order to fix the whole code, if there are more than one mistakes here?)

thanks in advance

XML sample with one product (Greek XML)

```
<mystore>
<created_at>2017-07-26 16:01:20</created_at>
<products>
<product>
<id>9307</id>
<name>
<![CDATA[ Minimum ανδρικό t-shirt φλάμα Percy ivory ]]>
</name>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.mydomain.gr/andrika-rouxa/tshirts-andrikes-mployzes/minimum-andriko-t-shirt-percy-ivory.html
]]>
</link>
<image>
<![CDATA[
https://www.mydomain.gr/images/detailed/51/minimum-andriko-t-shirt-percy-122690105_(1).jpg
]]>
</image>
<sku>
<![CDATA[ 122690105-wh ]]>
</sku>
<mpn>
<![CDATA[ 122690105-wh ]]>
</mpn>
<category id="30">
<![CDATA[ ΑΝΔΡΙΚΑ > T- shirts ]]>
</category>
<price>27.30</price>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<ul><li>χρώμα ελεφαντόδοντου</li><li>στρογγυλή λαιμόκοψη</li><li>στρογγυλεμένο και μακρύτερο πίσω μέρος</li><li>regular fit</li><li>100% cotton</li></ul>
]]>
</description>
<instock>Y</instock>
<availability>Σε απόθεμα</availability>
<manufacturer>
<![CDATA[ Minimum ]]>
</manufacturer>
<size>L,XL</size>
<sex>
<![CDATA[ Άνδρας ]]>
</sex>
</product>
</products>
</mystore>
```

date_modified is varchar(128) in my DB - utf8_general_ci
I do not think this is an issue, right?

Comment: @Parfait I have edit my question.. thanks for take time to reply..

Comment: Which `UPDATE` does not work? The very first one before loop or the one with `INSERT`? Please explain what does work. Do records append and update except for *date_modified*? If this field is a `varchar` as you claim, the first update could not fail even though you pass in an integer, `strtotime()` as MySQL will cast accordingly.

Comment: Do note your `INSERT` does not touch *date_modified*, only *date_added*. So those records would be `NULL` for *date_ modified*. Carefully check your data and report specific problem.

Comment: INSERT  is for new products that XML has but I don't (in my db)..that is why I am using $date which I want to insert in column date_added.. On the other hand, if product id exists, I would like to UPDATE it, by updating the column date_modified.. Is it more clear now of what I am trying to do?

Comment: I know what you are trying to do but don't know what's working or not? Which `UPDATE` query is the problem? Does the `INSERT` work?

Comment: Actually, in order to understand more about what it is working or not as you mentioned, I have a local XML file with 36 records... I have run my cronjob PHP script that I am working on, and I see that **date_modified** has changed... but I also changed the price of a product from 45€ to 55€ for example..and saw that **the price did not changed..** So, I am guessing that UPDATE is not working correctly.. Moreover, I have **add** another product record as a 37th one.. This record does not INSERTed to DB... I am still getting total products: 36 as before.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a *products_temp* table, exact structure of *products* but only used to store XML data. From there run needed append and update queries to migrate from temp to final table.

And definitely if there's any takeaway here, use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) which avoids quote enclosures and variable concatenation for cleaner, safer, maintainable code.

**XML Data** Handling *(append query inside loop)*

```
// CLEAN OUT TEMP TABLE
$sql = 'DELETE FROM products_temp';
$delete_xml = $conn->query($sql);

// PREPARED STATEMENT
$sql = 'INSERT INTO products_temp (business_id, pid, `name`, `category`, product_link, price,
                                   size, color, weight, `description`, manufacturer, mpn, ean,
                                   image, sku, instock, availability, `status`, date_added) 
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

// APPEND ALL RAW XML DATA INTO TEMP TABLE (IN LOOP, WITHOUT INNER IF LOGIC)
//...same xml objects

while($reader->read()) {
    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'product') {
        //...same xml variables
        $product = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXml());
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssss", 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($pid)), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($name)), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($category_path))), 
                          $check_product_url, 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($price)), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim(strtolower($size)))), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim(strtolower($color)))), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($weight))), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($description))), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim(strtolower($manufacturer)))), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($mpn))), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($ean))), 
                          $product_image, 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes(trim($sku))), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($instock)), 
                          mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,stripslashes($availability)), 
                          $status, 
                          $date);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

**Temp Data** Handling  *(outside loop, each called once, avoids using arrays and other `foreach`)*

Using the [`WHERE NOT EXISTS`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

```
// APPEND ONLY NEW TEMP PRODUCTS WITH RELEVANT INFO AND NOT IN SPECIAL CATEGS INTO PRODUCTS
$sql = 'INSERT INTO products (business_id, pid, `name`, `categor`y, product_link, price,
                              size, color, weight, `description`, manufacturer, mpn, ean,
                              image, sku, instock, availability, `status`, date_added) 
        SELECT t.business_id, t.pid, t.name, t.category, t.product_link, t.price,
               t.size, t.color, t.weight, t.description, t.manufacturer, t.mpn, t.ean,
               t.image, t.sku, t.instock, t.availability, t.status, t.date_added
        FROM products_temp t
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products sub 
                          WHERE sub.p_id = t.p_id AND sub.business_id = t.business_id)
          AND t.image IS NOT NULL AND t.price IS NOT NULL AND t.name IS NOT NULL 
          AND t.link IS NOT NULL AND t.manufacturer IS NOT NULL
          AND t.category_id NOT IN (604, 613, 635)';
$insert_business_xml = $conn->query($sql);
```

Using `UPDATE INNER JOIN`

```
// UPDATE MATCHED TEMP PROUCTS WITH MISSING RELEVANT INFO OR IN SPECIAL CATEGS (I.E., ERRORS)
$sql = 'UPDATE products p INNER JOIN products_temp t
                           ON p.p_id = t.p_id AND p.business_id = t.business_id
        SET p.status=0, p.date_modified = ?
        WHERE t.image IS NULL OR t.price IS NULL OR t.name IS NULL 
           OR t.link IS NULL OR t.manufacturer IS NULL
           OR t.category IN (604, 613, 635)';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date_modified);

$stmt->execute();
$count_errors = $mysqli->affected_rows;     // ERRORS FOR MESSAGE AT END


// UPDATE EXISTING MATCHED TEMP PRODUCTS WITH RELEVANT INFO AND NOT IN SPECIAL CATEGS
$sql = 'UPDATE products p INNER JOIN products_temp t
                           ON p.p_id = t.p_id AND p.business_id = t.business_id
        SET p.business_id = t.business_id, p.name = t.name, p.category = t.category, 
            p.product_link = t.product_link, p.price = t.price, p.size = t.size, 
            p.color = t.color, p.weight = t.weight, p.description = t.description, 
            p.manufacturer = t.manufacturer, p.mpne = t.mpn, p.ean = t.ean,
            p.image = t.image, p.sku = t.sku, p.instock = t.instock, 
            p.availability = t.availability, p.status = t.status, p.date_added = t.date_added
        WHERE t.image IS NOT NULL AND t.price IS NOT NULL AND t.name IS NOT NULL 
          AND t.link IS NOT NULL AND t.manufacturer IS NOT NULL
          AND t.category_id NOT IN (604, 613, 635)';
$update_business_xml = $conn->query($sql);


// UPDATE EXISTING NON-MATCHED TEMP PRODUCTS
$sql = 'UPDATE products p SET p.status = 0
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products_temp sub 
                          WHERE sub.p_id = p.p_id AND sub.business_id = p.business_id)';
$update_business_xml = $conn->query($sql);
```

*Note: Of course without actual data and database all this is untested. Please adjust any overlooked syntax and integrate in larger codebase.*

Comment: I think I understood what prepare and "ssssss" works.. You are using questionmarks ..?,?,?... inside mysql queries and after that you are using prepare ->($sql) and with bind_param("s",$date_modified); you are like replacing the s with the variable, right? But still some questions though... I am getting this error: "_italic_ Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables _italic_"
in this line of code you are saying:
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date_modified);
$stmt->execute();
$count_errors = $mysqli->affected_rows;

Comment: if I have one "s" and one "?" inside mysql I should have one variable ($date_modified), right?

Comment: Correct. Please read the plethora of offline/online docs and tutorials on php/mysqli parameterization. Yes `?` is the placeholder and `s` defines *string* type (use `i` for *integer* types). As for error, you have 19 values being passed in append query and I counted 17 so I added two more question marks and s's.

Comment: ok I did my tests and works in some cases.. When the XML file is not big enough, UPDATES & INSERTS works. But when XML files are big, I am getting a 500 internal server error.. and a PHP warning message (in logs files) [29-Jul-2017 11:15:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (42000/1226): User '*****' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30) in /path/to/my/cronjob/file/cronjob.php on line 16 .. .. .. Should I change my php.ini file for that? this is not a very fast a good idea with all these inserts and then updates, right? I guess.. ..